# Custom product option price ignored by backend when making new order

Tags: admin, orders, price, product-attribute, ce-1.9.1.0

When making a new order in the magento admin backend the website price for a custom option is ignored and uses the default.

The frontend works fine the issue is only from admin.

the issue only happens when you get the shipping price,

The website "price" is used but any custom option that has an additional charge (eg +£20) will use the default price what ever it might be.

Comment: Any ideas on this?

Comment: With what shipping method did this happen? It worked for me on table rates